# How can I quickly find where my stuff is after dying?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died on a flatland in Minecraft and you can go off maps on flatlands. I made some really important stuff (for school) and I cant find it.

What should I do?

Comment: "Stuff" is what exactly? (Something you built, or perhaps items you dropped?) You could use a compass to get back to to map spawn, but if whatever you lost isn't near that then you're pretty much screwed. There are mods which can track your position, but I doubt they will work if installed after the event.

Comment: Second on this request for more information.  If you mean stuff such as "items", then you'll need to rush to where you've died to pick up your gear again.  (These items will fade out of exsistance after some time has pass, or when that chunk is unloaded.)

Answer (score 1):

By "Stuff" I assume you mean some buildings that you have made. The best way to solve this is to create a full sized map of the area. To do this use a [mapping program](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Mapping), I would recommend [Mapcrafter](http://mapcrafter.org/index), instructions on how to use it can be found [here](http://docs.mapcrafter.org/builds/stable/using_mapcrafter.html). Any one of these programs should map all the chunks in the map showing you where your buildings are. If you would like any help on your project you can use a map editor like [Mcedit](http://www.mcedit.net/).

Comment: Side talk: I think it's against the spirit of this site to suggest 3rd-party tools and applications as answers, unless there's no other options.  In this case, there's better options to use in game first.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer. This is the best way I can think of to locate buildings. I doubt they are items because you can't really play a superflat map without creative mode so getting the items back would be trivial.